# Grunt watch interrupt not working with jekyll

Tags: gruntjs, jekyll, grunt-contrib-watch

So I'm new to Grunt and have been trying to implement a workflow for it and Jekyll. So I have a watch task running but it seems to fail to interrupt the current serve task before trying to start Jekyll again because I get an error about port binding, specifically **jekyll 2.0.3 | Error:  Address already in use - bind(2)**

It could be me doing something stupid or not understanding something but does anyone have any ideas? Here's my gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
// load time-grunt and all grunt plugins found in the package.json
require( 'time-grunt' )( grunt );
require( 'load-grunt-tasks' )( grunt );
grunt.initConfig({
    csslint : {
        test : {
            options : {
                import : 2
            },
            src : [ 'css/main.css' ]
        }
    },

    cssmin : {
        dist : {
            src : 'css/main.css',
            dest : 'css/main.min.css'
        }
    },

    shell : {
        jekyllBuild : {
            command : 'glynn'
        },
        jekyllServe : {
            command : 'jekyll serve'
        }
    },

    watch : {
        files : [ '_layouts/*.html',
                  '_posts/*.md',
                  'css/main.css',
                  '_config.yml',
                  'index.html',
                  '404.html' ],
        tasks : [ 'cssmin',
                  'shell:jekyllServe' ],
        options : {
            spawn : true,
            interrupt : true,
            atBegin : true,
            debounceDelay: 250
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

// register custom grunt tasks
grunt.registerTask( 'lintcheck', [ 'cssmin','csslint', 'shell:jekyllServe' ] )
grunt.registerTask( 'qbuild', [ 'cssmin', 'shell:jekyllServe' ] )
grunt.registerTask( 'deploy', [ 'cssmin', 'shell:jekyllBuild' ] )
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an error because you tried to run `jekyll serve` more than once (while server was already running). As you can read in the docs, `jekyll serve` runs a development server at localhost:4000 (http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/) so you can fire it only one on a particular port at the same time. After that you need only rebuild jekyll into ./_site when some files changed. You can do that with `jekyll build`.

I modified your Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
// load time-grunt and all grunt plugins found in the package.json
require( 'time-grunt' )( grunt );
require( 'load-grunt-tasks' )( grunt );
grunt.initConfig({
    csslint : {
        test : {
            options : {
                import : 2
            },
            src : [ 'css/main.css' ]
        }
    },

    cssmin : {
        dist : {
            src : 'css/main.css',
            dest : 'css/main.min.css'
        }
    },

    shell : {
        jekyllBuildLocal : {
            command : 'jekyll build'
        },
        jekyllBuild : {
            command : 'glynn'
        },
        jekyllServe : {
            command : 'jekyll serve'
        }
    },

    watch : {
        files : [ '_layouts/*.html',
                  '_posts/*.md',
                  'css/main.css',
                  '_config.yml',
                  'index.html',
                  '404.html' ],
        tasks : [ 'cssmin',
                  'shell:jekyllBuildLocal' ],
        options : {
            spawn : true,
            interrupt : true,
            atBegin : true,
            debounceDelay: 250
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-csslint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

// register custom grunt tasks
grunt.registerTask( 'lintcheck', [ 'cssmin','csslint', 'shell:jekyllBuildLocal' ] )
grunt.registerTask( 'qbuild', [ 'cssmin', 'shell:jekyllBuildLocal' ] )
grunt.registerTask( 'deploy', [ 'cssmin', 'shell:jekyllBuild' ] )
};
```

And what I recommend you for development is to run:

1. `grunt shell:jekyllServe`
2. `grunt watch` (I guess in other terminal window)

This should work properly

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a site with a similar workflow but with Gulp instead of Grunt. I swapped the default jekyll server with browserSync, which also auto-reloads pages when changes are made (useful in development). [This](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/96d03c316f5bd6d51878) is an example Gulp build file; a Grunt-equivalent can be made.

Comment: Thanks for this - although it didn't fix it the issue its given me a perfect workaround. Many thanks!